# connecting the negative positive terminals of two dc to dc converter

Tags: dc

I require two voltages for my device  22 and -20 is it possible to use two dc to dc converter to generate the two voltage and connect the negative and positive output terminals, and that will be my reference ground. is it ok or is it bad idea

Answer (score 1):

No, this works fine providing the outputs are isolated types. I've done this a few times. You can even add multiple outputs to get oddball voltages. For instance I used a 30V output and a 3V3 output but subtracted the outputs to get 26.7 volts.

Here's a picture of two devices powered from a common supply but producing negative and positive 5V: -

[image]

Just read the small print to make sure the outputs are isolated. [Here's](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/138244/sanity-check-input-and-output-filter-for-a-stacked-pair-of-dc-dc-converters) a stack exchange post that does the same.